# shm_open() leads to a No such file or directory

Tags: c, memory, system, shared-memory, shared

### Description :

I have a project directory named "Projet" which contain two directory named "Serveur" and "Client".

(1) Serveur contains serveur.c (2) Client contains client.c

Referenting to [the man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html), I choose as a name : "/shm_request_stack".

**Source files description :**

serveur.c :

```
#define SHM_REQUEST "/shm_request_stack"

int main(void) {
    sem_t shm = open_shm(SHM_REQUEST,
                         O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL,
                         S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    unlink_shm(SHM_REQUEST);

    size_t memsize = sizeof(int);
    setsize_shm(shm, memsize);

    int * ptr = project_shm(shm, memsize);
    *ptr = 0;

    while(*ptr == 0);
    printf("Client modify the value\n");
}
```

client.c :

```
#define SHM_REQUEST "/shm_request_stack"

int main(void) {
    sem_t shm = open_shm(SHM_REQUEST,
                         O_RDWR,
                         S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    unlink_shm(SHM_REQUEST);

    size_t memsize = sizeof(int);
    int * ptr = project_shm(shm, memsize);

    *ptr = 1;
}
```

**Envelope functions**

```
int open_shm(char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode) {
    int shm = shm_open(name, oflag, mode);
    if (shm == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return shm;
}

void unlink_shm(char *name) {
    if (shm_unlink(name) == -1) {
        perror("sem_unlink");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void setsize_shm(int shm, size_t size) {
    if (ftruncate(shm, size) == -1) {
        perror("ftruncate");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void * project_shm(int shm, size_t size) {
    int *ptr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm, 0);
    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

**Problems :**

The client can't find the named shm create by the server.
I tried to found the shared memory with `ipcs -m` but I've not.

I try to modify the value from the server and it's works so the memory exist.

How can I successfully open the shm from the client ?

Comment: I tried to launch the both program with sudo but i got the same result

Comment: Is the server still running when you run the client?

Comment: Yes, he still running and waiting for the value to be modify

Comment: You appear to be deleting the shared object immediately after creating it (`unlink`)!  Why?  I think that is the problem.  Comment out the `unlink` and try again.

Comment: "the removal of the memory object contents shall be postponed until all open and map references to the shared memory object have been removed", but it's look like it have something to do with that. 

I try some manipulation and come for editing after

(edit)  That was the problem, but why the documentation said that the memory will be erase only after the processus calling unlink closed ?

Comment: It is a bit like a file.  If you have an open reference to the object then it is retained, but the `unlink` removes the *name*. That is why the server can still write to the object after the `unlink` (`shm` is still in scope), but the client cannot open the object by name.  The critical words in the doc you quote are : "*all open and map references*" - what you can't do is create a new reference after the `unlock`.

Comment: Ok, i got it, thanks you !

Comment: Entered comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be deleting the shared object immediately after creating it (`unlink`).

It is a bit like a file. If you have an open reference to the object then it is retained, but the `unlink` removes the name. That is why the server can still write to the object after the `unlink` (`she` is still in scope), but the client cannot open the object by name.

The critical words in the doc you quote are : "*all open and map references*" - what you can't do is create a new reference after the `unlink`.